# To polymorph or to incapsulate, this is the question! (C++)

Tags: c++, polymorphism, encapsulation

I need to store a polymorphic object (let's say `Polygon`) inside another object (let's say `Simulation`). At the same time I want to keep encapsulation of `Simulation`.

```
class Polygon {
public:
  virtual double area() { return 0; }
};

class Square : public Polygon {
public:
  Square(double edge) : edge_(edge) {}
  virtual double area() { return edge_*edge_; }
private:
  double edge_;
};

class Simulation {
public:
  Simulation(Polygon& polygon) { polygon_ = &polygon; }
  Polygon* polygon() { return polygon_; }
private:
  Polygon* polygon_;
};

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  Square square(2.0);
  Simulation sim(square);
  std::cout<<sim.polygon()->area()<<"\n";
  return 0;
}
```

This works perfectly fine! However, it violates encapsulation of `Simulation`, in fact, if from the `main` I go and change `square` it will also change inside `Simulation`.

I was thinking of modifying the constructor of `Simulation` using the copy constructor as:

```
Simulation(Polygon& polygon) { polygon_ = new Polygon(polygon); }
```

but this will mean that I don't have polymorphism...

There is obviously something I am missing here... CHEERS!

Comment: Do you want square to be unchangeable once Simulations gets it's hands on it? Or I mean square can't be changed outside of the Simulation class.

Comment: You can think of `polygon` as an injected dependency. If the caller can provide any instance of the `Polygon` base/interface class, then in particular they can provide one that they're capable of manipulating directly. I wouldn't consider that a problem - encapsulation is there because callers *want* things to be encapsulated, so if they're smart they'll pass in the instance of `Polygon`, whether that's `Square` or some other derived class, and then forget about it. The documentation of `Simulation` should specify all required behavior, including any assumptions about the polygon not changing.

Comment: What is the role of those objects? Contrary to what certain OOP fanatics will have you believe, design depends on context and on what you actually need. Why is the Polygon's role in the application? How does it interact with Simulation? Who is responsible for creating the Polygon? Does it *need* to be exposed to users of the Simulation? Where and how do you need polymorphism? Simply saying "but then I don't have polymorphism" is inane. The only sane response is "well? Do you need it? Why?"

Comment: @jalf I am sorry, but I don't get what you mean. My question is about polymorphism. And yes, I **do** need polymorphism. It makes perfect sense in my case. The real objects are `microphone` => `omnidirectional microphone`, `kemar microphone`, etc, and my simulation should work with any of those regardless of the specific type.

Comment: @Enzo: The fact that you can't do `Simulation sim(Square(2.0))` (because a temporary can't be bound to a non-const reference) is what encourages you to write `Square sq(2.0); Simulation sim(sq);`. Writing that ensures that `sim` doesn't outlive `sq`. If you really want the `Simulation` to take ownership of the `Polygon` then you *could* pass it by `auto_ptr`, or `shared_ptr` for shared ownership. This would solve the lifetime issue, but of course not the encapsulation issue. It's a *desired* property of dependency injection that the user interacts with the injected object, it's how mocks work.

Comment: In short, the *point* of polymorphism is that the caller passes you a "black box". It implements the interface `Polygon`, and other than that you don't know what it does. In particular, it might continue to communicate with whoever created it. You can't prevent that, so you may as well embrace it, and specify what's required to avoid messing up `Simulation`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a clone function to Polygon (and a virtual destructor!).  It is a good idea to ensure that Polygon is abstract so make sure at least one function is pure virtual.

Your Simulation class will require a copy constructor, destructor and assignment operator.
Note that the Square clone function can return a Square* even though the super class returns a Polygon* because it is covariant.  Some older compilers may not support this, in which case return a Polygon*.

```
class Polygon {
public:
  virtual ~Polygon() = 0;
  virtual Polygon* clone() const = 0;
  virtual double area() { return 0; }
};
inline Polygon::~Polygon() {}

class Square : public Polygon {
public:
  Square(double edge) : edge_(edge) {}
  virtual Square* clone() const { return new Square(*this); }
  virtual double area() { return edge_*edge_; }
private:
  double edge_;
};

class Simulation {
public:
  Simulation(Polygon const& polygon) 
  : polygon_(polygon.clone())
  {}
  Simulation(Simulation const& rhs) 
  : polygon_(rhs.polygon_->clone())
  {}
  Simulation& operator=(Simulation const& rhs) 
  {
      if (this != &rhs) {
          delete polygon_;
          polygon_ = rhs.polygon_->clone();
      }
      return *this;
  }
  ~Simulation() {
     delete polygon_;
  }
  Polygon* polygon() { return polygon_; }
private:
  Polygon* polygon_;
};
```

Comment: If you recommend this manual memory management monstrosity, you better make this exception-safe! What if `clone()` throws?

Comment: Kerrek, disable exceptions and you're set. :)

Comment: @Kerrek - well spotted - operator= is not exception safe.

Answer (score 1):

If `Simulation` contains `Polygon` then it means that it is meant to do something with it.  If you need to access the polygon directly from the 'outside', you have either missed the design somewhere, or if not, you can use observer pattern and have polygon notify the simulation if something about it changes.

So, either:

```
outside -> polygon -> callback -> simulation
```

or

```
outside -> simulation -> polygon
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to make sure that there's no way for outside code to alter the inner polygon of simulation, but yet allow any subclass to be used inside it? I.e. make sure that there are no references outside of simulation to the object passed by ref in the c'tor?

You could think of an abstract copy method to accomplish that: (don't forget to `delete` in simulation destructor)

```
class Polygon {
public:
   virtual Polygon *copy() = 0;
   //..
};
class Square : public Polygon {
public:
   virtual Polygon *copy() { return new Square(_edge); }
   //...
}
class Simulation {
public:
   Simulation(const Polygon &p) : poly(p.copy()) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to decide if the polygon is inside or outside of simulation. If it's supposed to be outside of it, then you have reference constructor parameter . If it's inside, you'll need the following code:

```
class Simulation {
public:
    Simulation() : poly(2.0) { }
    Polygon *polygon() { return &poly; }
private:
    Square poly;
};
```

Now, the polymorphism aspect you can easily do like this:

```
class Simulation {
public:
    Simulation() : poly(2.0), poly2(3.0) { }
    Polygon *polygon(int i) 
   { 
       switch(i) { 
          case 0: return &poly;  
          case 1: return &poly2; 
       } 
       return 0; 
   }
private:
    Square poly;
    Cylinder poly2;
};
```

And once you get tired to adding new data members, here's another trick which will fix some cases:

```
class Simulation {
public:
    Simulation() : poly(2.0) { }
    Polygon *polygon(float x) 
    {
        poly.edge_ = x;
        return &poly;
    }
private:
    Square poly;
 };
```

Edit: Note that the order of classes in header file needs to be carefully considered.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy a polymorphic object, this can be done with a clone method.

```
class Polygon
{
  ...
  virtual Polygon* clone() const = 0;
};

class Square: public Polygon
{
  ...
  virtual Square* clone() const { return new Square(*this); }
};
```

However, in the example it seems a bit pointless that the Simulation neither does anything with the polygon itself nor do you want to hand it out for other code to use.

Answer (score 0):

That's just how C++ works. If you write a wrapper for an object (PIMPL) you have to implement its full interface. The functions going to be very small just passing the calls to the actual implementation but you have to write them. Then you can alter the behaviour, add logging, or whatever you need...